# jquery is(:visible) for visibility : hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In jQuery:

```
e.is(':visible');
```

checks if an element is displayed or not.

**Is there an function in jQuery to check if an element has the attribute visibility to hidden or visible?**

Now I have to make that function myself. But i want to use the jQuery function instead if it exists.

The function I made:

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
    return ($(this).css('opacity') != '0' && $(this).css('visibility') !== 'hidden');
};
```

To extend my example: 
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6k518gu/4/)

**The real question is: Is there a jQuery function or not?**

Comment: use attribute selector

Comment: btw you're only checking for opacity. Do you think opacity is enough? :) and also you have an extra `)` in your code

Comment: `$(e).css( "visibility") == "hidden" `

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan From documentation: "***Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible***"

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan it was a quick paste, sorted afterwards ;)

Comment: So i also quick pasted my code.. sorry for the EXTRA ')' bothering you.. But thanks for the response :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Just pointing out that .is(":hidden") will return false for an element with css visibility: hidden; Your comment tries to suggest otherwise

Comment: @Esko yes yes dummy me :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check css property visibility is set to visible or hidden.

```
if ($("#element").css("visibility") === "visible") {
    //...
}
```

or in your case:

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
    return $(this).css('visibility') === 'visible';
};
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already knew this. The real question i'm asking if there is a jQuery function for this

Comment: @Nebulosar if there were one we would post you the link to the DOCS ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well, you never know.. nobody answered my direct question yet: is there a jquery function or not? I wasn't asking for options to do this, just that question, cause i already have a sollution.. :)

Comment: No there is no jquery function for this.

Comment: @athimohan THANK YOU!

Comment: Noticing that this works because jQuery [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#entry-longdesc) gets the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value). So a visibility-hidden parent makes the child look visibility-hidden too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#test').css('visibility');` to get the value of visibility

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm taking there isn't a jQuery function to check this?

Comment: css is a jquery function to provide you a value but the comparison you need to do